# ¿Porqué no enlaza el origen de datos de dataset?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quiero hacer un reporte con reportviewer pero me sale que no hay ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen. Tengo creado dataset y origen de datos.

Comment: Puedes ver si está correctamente realizado la conexión a la sql-server? Muestra qué te sale en el asistente de conexión.

Comment: Mi conexión a sql-server lo hago mediante el data set de origen de datos y el informe me pide lo mismo @Isanchezo

Comment: Hay datos en la BD? si abres con sql o el manejador de Bd que estes utilizando, hay datos?

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahí coloco el origen de datos como ves pongo el origen de datos y la tabla que quiero mostrar.

Comment: Esto deberia ser parte de la pregunta no una respuesta